# Performance Monitor .NET Data Provider for SqlServer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to troubleshoot an ASP.NET Core application that periodically gets a database connection pool timeout. In Windows Performance Monitor there are counters under .NET Data Provider for SqlServer that should allow me to monitor the connection pool, but when I try to add any of the counters under that section no instances are displayed so it won't allow me to add the counter. There server is Windows Server 2016 Datacenter running on AWS.

Comment: Are you trying to monitor [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/performance-counters) that are off-by-default? Some of the counters need to be enabled in application configuration files.

Comment: Yes, but even the ones that are not off be default aren't working.